# Binding and checking radiobuttons in Knockout JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Having some more problems with knockout JS and was hoping someone would be able to help me. (The amount of questions I have had to ask about Knockout I wonder if maybe I should have stuck with jQuery)

I am trying to dynamically create a list of radio buttons with two or three options. Each row is a seperate group of buttons.

I can write out the list okay but I am struggling to get the right ones to check or not.

The HTML I have is:

```
<div data-bind="with: functions" id="ActionWindow">
<h2>bob<span data-bind="text: pgroupname"></span></h2>

<h2>Read & Update Functions</h2>

<div>
<table>
    <thead class="FunctionsTableHead">
        <tr>
            <th class="FunctionName">Function</th>
            <th>None</th>
            <th>Read</th>
            <th>Write</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="FunctionsTable" data-bind="foreach: pReadFunctions">
        <tr>
            <td class="FunctionName" data-bind="text: FunctionName"></td>
            <td><label><input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: FunctionNum + '-ReadAccessLevel'}, checkedValue: 0, checked: AccessLevel" /></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: FunctionNum + '-ReadAccessLevel'}, checkedValue: 1, checked: AccessLevel" /></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: FunctionNum + '-ReadAccessLevel'}, checkedValue: 2, checked: AccessLevel" /></label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
</div>

<h2>Action Functions</h2>

    <table>
    <thead class="FunctionsTableHead">
        <tr>
            <th class="FunctionName">Function</th>
            <th>None</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="FunctionsTable" data-bind="foreach: pActionFunctions">
        <tr>
            <td class="FunctionName" data-bind="text: FunctionName"></td>
            <td><label><input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: FunctionNum + '-ActionAccessLevel'}, checkedValue: 0, checked: AccessLevel" /></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { name: FunctionNum + '-ActionAccessLevel'}, checkedValue: 1, checked: AccessLevel" /></label></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

I have tried two different approaches for the two lists of radio buttons but neither have worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//slide animation for lefthand menu 
$('.ListDeptLink').click(function () {
    $(this).nextAll('.SectListDiv').first().slideToggle(500);
});

$('.ListSectLink').click(function () {

    var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayGroup", "AjaxGroup")' + '?GroupId=' + $(this).attr("GroupId") + "&GroupName=" + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr("GroupName"));

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: 'POST',
        context: this,
        timeout: 60000,
        dataType: 'json',
        tryCount: 0,
        retryLimit: 3,
        success: function (data) {
            viewModel.functions(new functionsModel(data))
        },
        error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
});

function functionsModel(data) {
    this.pgroupname = ko.observable(data ? data.GroupName : "");
    this.FunctionNum = data ? data.FunctionNum : "";
    this.AccessLevel = data ? data.AccessLevel : "";

    this.pReadFunctions = ko.observableArray((data ? data.ReadFunctionList : [])
        .map(function (item) {
            return {
                FunctionNum: item.FunctionNum,
                FunctionName: item.FunctionName,
                AccessLevel: ko.observable(item.AccessLevel)
            };
        })
    );

    this.pActionFunctions = ko.observableArray((data ? data.ActionFunctionList : [])
        .map(function (item) {
            return {
                FunctionNum: item.FunctionNum,
                FunctionName: item.FunctionName,
                AccessLevel: ko.observable(item.AccessLevel)
            };
        })
    );
};

var wrapper = function () {
    this.functions = ko.observable(new functionsModel(null));
};

var viewModel = new wrapper();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And finally an example of the data coming back:

```
ReadFunctionList":[],"ActionFunctionList":     [{"FunctionNum":582,"FunctionName":"Name1","FunctionType":Ignorethis,"GroupNum":1,"AccessLevel":0},{"FunctionNum":502,"FunctionName":"Name2","FunctionType":IgnoreThis,"GroupNum":2,"AccessLevel":0},"GroupName":"Name1"}
```

The AccessLevel is what determines which should be ticked so in this example both items should have the first radiobutton ticked.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**Edit: I have updated the code with where I have got to so far**

Comment: A working jsfiddle showing the issue would be great

Comment: I'm working on it but I can't even get the JS Fiddle to populate the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/dariune/sYTF7/

Comment: Your first problem is that you're not following any of the design patterns that you should with knockout. You're mixing knockout and jQuery and using jQuery to do things that should be handled with knockout. I strongly suggest you follow the knockout tutorials and structure your code like it is there.

Comment: Look at your wrapper function.  You create an observableArray then populate with a non-array value, remove the second line.  The same with the success callback.  That really should push a new value into the observableArray -> viewModel.functions.push(new functionsModel(data)) ;

Comment: In terms of getting the jsFiddle to work, replace the AJAX call in the click event with a direct assignment to viewModel.functions...  Also, where are the elements where JQuery is wiring the click handlers to.  You're also missing a binding from wrapper to functions ( "foreach: functions" ? )

Comment: Hi all. I have updated my JSFiddle with my current code using the suggestions made os far: http://jsfiddle.net/sYTF7/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sYTF7/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript issues**

I think that functions in wrapper should be an observable, not observableArray.

```
var wrapper = function () {
    this.functions= ko.observable(new functionsModel(null));
};
```

Your pReadFunction and pActionFunction items should have the AccessLevel property as an observable.  You won't get updates from changing the radio buttons into the viewmodel.

```
// Inside $('.ListSectLink').click
this.pReadFunctions = ko.observableArray( (data ? data.ReadFunctionList : [] )
    .map( function(item) {
        return {
            FunctionNum: item.FunctionNum,
            FunctionName: item.FunctionName,
            FunctionType: item.FunctionType,
            GroupNum: item.GroupNum,
            AccessLevel: ko.observable(item.AccessLevel)
        }; 
    })
);

// Repeat for pActionFunctions
```

In your jsFiddle, don't use an AJAX call in your click handler, just assign your sample data directly.  If you really want to simulate an Async callback, use $.Deferred / resolveWith.

```
$('.ListSectLink').click(function () {
    var testData = ...
    viewModel.functions( new functionsModel(testData) );
});

$('.ListSectLink').click(function () {
    var testData = ...
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    deferred.done( function(data) {
        this.functions( new functionsModel(data) );
    });

    setTimeout( function() {
        deferred.resolveWith(viewModel, [testData]);
    }, 100);

});
```

**HTML/Binding Issues**

In your jsFiddle it's missing wrapper->functions binding.  That is probably why the sample doesn't work.  Assuming something like.

```
<div data-bind="with: functions" />
```

Input Radios checked binding should not be against $root.  That would be *wrapper* instance in your example.  Given your sample JSON the AccessLevel is on each of the ReadFunctionList and ActionFunctionList array item, therefore use "$data.AccessLevel" ( or just "AccessLevel" ) for the checked data-bind

The checked binding does a compare against the element's value and the backing observable.  But the element's binding is a **string**, but in your sample JSON it's a **number**.  This will not match.  Add a checkedValue data-bind expression to override the "value" of each radio button to be a numeric.

You also need to use the name attr binding for the pReadFunction radio buttons like you do for the pActionFunction radio buttons to group each row into a set.  You may also consider adding another prefix to both Read and Action in case FunctionNum is not unique between the 2 sets.

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="
    attr: { name: 'Action-' + FunctionNum + '-AccessLevel'}, 
    checkedValue: 0,
    checked: AccessLevel" />

<input type="radio" data-bind="
    attr: { name: 'Action-' + FunctionNum + '-AccessLevel'}, 
    checkedValue: 1,
    checked: AccessLevel" />
```

**Bonus Points**

You can also use a click binding instead of using jQuery.  The click function would be a function on the wrapper class.  You need to pass in the Url as it look like that is generated server-side.  I'm using a button to wire up the data-bind for the example.  You'll probably need to help the razor engine work out client-side and server-side inside the data-bind attribute.  I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader ;)

The benefit here is that all the model manipulation is containing within the viewModel.  Also note the *bind* statement on the click data-bind expression.  This is the way you get arguments into a function.  If "wrapper" is not the root object, you might need to change it to $data or $parent depending on your real applyBindings/viewModel structure.  In the jsFiddle it will work.

```
<button data-bind="click: getListSectLink.bind($root, @Url.Action(...)">Get</button>

function wrapper() {
    this.functions = ko.observable( new FunctionsModel(null ) );
    this.getListSectLink = function(url) {
         // ajax stuff
         success: function(data) {
             this.functions( new functionsModel(data) );
         }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hiya, thankyou for the extensive reply. I have edited my JSFiddle and my code and still can't get it working. On my code it writes out the list of data but doesn't have anything ticked. On the JSFiddle I can't even get it to write out the data. 

Would you mind having a look? http://jsfiddle.net/sYTF7/2/

Comment: I have updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYTF7/7/).  Your version didn't have jQuery referenced and I have updated the knockout version to 3.0.0 as the checked/checkedValue bindings have been enhanced.   If you must use 2.3.0 then you will still need to use the value attribute on each input radio  and the AccessLevel observable will become a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Knockout uses an exact comparison to figure out which radio button to select, and you are binding to an integer `checked` value while giving the radio buttons a string `attr` value. The solution is to use the `checkedValue` binding (instead of `attr`) to give the radio buttons an integer value:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue: FunctionNum, checked: $root.AccessLevel" />
```

Reference: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html#parameters

Comment: This is a 3.0.0 feature, and the checked binding is incorrect